# iPython REPLs are receiving bad characters from text editors (Windows 10)

Tags: character-encoding, ipython, text-editor, read-eval-print-loop, neovim

I want a vim-like text editor to send code to REPLs including iPython *in Windows*. In Linux [SLIMUX](https://github.com/esamattis/slimux) is perfect. (I use WSL often, but sometimes it's inconvenient.)

Let's start with ATOM's [platformio-ide-terminal](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal) package. Here's the code I send:

[image]

and here's what get's sent to the iPython REPL running in Powershell:

[image]

For ordinary Python it does not do that; it works fine.

Let's go to NeoVim's [iron.nvim](https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim), where things are even worse for iPython when sending a selection (`<Plug>(iron-send-motion)`):

[image]

In addition to adding extra characters, the iron.nvim send-selection command fails to even execute the command (an [issue](https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim/issues/135) logged on Github). The just sits in the REPL until you switch vim windows, go into insert mode, and press enter. While it will not add extra characters to ordinary Python, it will still not execute it (this could be a separate issue).

What's going on with iPython and these extra characters? Is there any way to fix it? Why, on Windows, is it so difficult to send code from a text editor to an arbitrary REPL?

Answer (score 0):

This post on the [emacs stack exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5/24572#24572) at least has a partial answer: At Version 5, iPython got a "new terminal interface" that was incompatible with Emacs' inferior shells. It makes sense that it would give Atom's and iron.nvim's a hard time as well.

For Atom, starting the shell with `ipython --simple-prompt` completely solves the problem. For iron.nvim, it at least gets rid of the bad characters. In iron.nvim, I've traded bad characters for the iPython multiline paste loosing its newlines, but that seems out of scope for this question.